# What is Shalom Aleichem?

Tags: words

What does Shalom Aleichem mean?

Is it a question (peace unto you) or a blessing or both?

> מסכת ברכות פרק ב
>   ב,א  היה קורא בתורה, והגיע זמן המקרא--אם כיוון את ליבו, יצא; ואם לאו, לא יצא.  ובפרקים שואל מפני הכבוד ומשיב, ובאמצע שואל מפני היראה ומשיב, דברי רבי מאיר.  רבי יהודה אומר, באמצע שואל מפני היראה ומשיב מפני הכבוד, ובפרקים שואל מפני הכבוד ומשיב שלום לכל אדם.
>
> מסכת ברכות פרק ה
>   א 
>   ...אפילו המלך שואל בשלומו, לא ישיבנו....
>
> ט,ז
>   ...התקינו שיהא אדם שואל את שלום חברו בשם...

Sholom alecha rebbi is also referred to as a question.

Where can i find a pilpul on this topic?

Related:

- [Why is "Shalom Aleichem" always plural?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/786/why-is-shalom-aleichem-always-plural)
- [Shalom Alaichem and vice versa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/778/shalom-alaichem-and-vice-versa)

**Edit**.
*Be the first to Shalom anybody*.
How can I fulfill this in America?
By saying how are you?

*Forbidden to ask Sholom of a woman*.
What does this mean?

Comment: See the last dar at the end of makkos

Comment: How is "peace on to you" a question?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude blessing "peace on to you" or a question "is peace on you"

Comment: Maybe since we can say it to all goim we meet, it is not a blessing, since it is forbidden to bless goim for nothing

Comment: Shouldn't the bits after "edit" be their own questions?

Comment: @DonielFilreis the answer to this question possibly answers those questions, the answer of those questions answer this question

Answer (score 6):

[Likutei Sichos 25 page 166](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14948&st=&pgnum=179) explains that the reason we say Shalom Aleichem in a Lashon Rabim since when 2 jews meet they are a Rabim and now they have to become B'Achdus by saying Aleichem each one shows they want peace. (Perhaps someone out there can explain it better than I did)

Comment: I love likutei sichos I don't think you can learn any rashi without it

Answer (score 5):

There was a decree that we greet people with Hashem's name (Brachos 54a) (and Hashem agreed to it (Makkos 23b)

> התקינו שיהא אדם שואל את שלום חברו בשם שנאמר והנה בעז בא מבית לחם ויאמר לקוצרים ה' עמכם ויאמרו לו יברכך ה' ואומר ה' עמך גבור החיל

Shalom is the name of Hashem,as it says in Shabbos 10b

> אין שם שאילת שלום מסייע ליה לרב המנונא משמיה דעולא דאמר אסור לאדם שיתן שלום לחבירו בבית המרחץ משום שנאמר ויקרא לו ה' שלום

One isn't allowed to say Shalom in a bath house as it's a name of Hashem.

Therefore, as Rashi on Makos writes:

> שאילת שלום בשם דחייב אדם לשאול בשלום חבירו בשם ואנו נמי כי שיילינן אהדדי מדכרינן שם דשלום שמו של הקב"ה דכתיב (שופטים ו) ויקרא לו ה' שלום לשם ה':

So when we say Shalom Aleichem, it's kind of like saying Hashem Imachem.

Comment: Is it blessing G-d is with you of a question is G-d with you

Comment: כי המתחיל ואומר לחבירו שלום עליך אינו ל' שאלה עד שתאמר שחבירו משיב לו שלום עלי וחוזר ונותן לו שלום דא"כ למה נותן לו שלום אלא הו"ל גם כן לשואלו בשלומו וא"ל שכן הוא באמת שחוזר ושואלו דהא אינו חוזר ומשיב לו חבירו השואלו תחילה ועוד דא"כ הול"ל השלום עליך בה"א אלא אין כאן שאלה ותשובה כלל אלא המתחיל אומר לו שלום עליך ר"ל מברכו בהשלום והוא מכפיל לו בשלום ואומר שלום עליך ועוד שלום וק"ל:   from the end of this https://www.sefaria.org/Drisha%2C_Yoreh_Deah.148.6.1